# Installer script runtime

Tags: mysql, install-script

When does the installer scripts run? Is there a function checking for new versions of extensions and installer scripts every time Magento loads?
The question is both for the exact time and place of the version update/install process and the subsequent installer script if present for a module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magentos checks all module versions for every setup script defined (there can be more than one per module), defined in `/config/modules/<YourModuleName>/version` against the one saved in `core_resource` table.

As long as the cache is activated this means in practice, that the scripts don't run, because the module version is saved in config cache.

When the config is merged, the scripts might run. There are two types of scripts:

- install scripts
- data scripts

These scripts are called with

```
Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates();
```

and

```
Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates();
```

There are a few differences, the big one is, install scripts don't know much about the installation, especially they don't know anything about existing websites, store views, etc.

I think to understand what is going on the easiest is, to have a few breakpoints in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php` to see the bootstrapping of magento.

In short:

```
index.php
|- Mage::run()
    |- Mage_Core_Model_App::run()
           |- Mage_Core_Model_App::_initModules()
           |   |- Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
           |- Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates();
```

Comment: So if the cache is not enabled this happens every time someone refresh a page?

Comment: I think it doesn't matter wether the cache is on or not. The check is made every time. The question is on which basis. And when the cache is on the cached data are used. If the cache is empty or off, the freshly merged config is used